# Updating two tables we getting duplicates

Tags: sql

I have two tables like

`emp`:

```
id  name sal deptno
-------------------
1    a    x   10
2    b    x   20
3    c    x   20
```

`dept`:

```
id sal deptno
-------------
1  100 10
2  200 20
3  300 20
```

Here I want to update `sal` column in `emp` table

```
update emp
set sal = d.sal
from emp as e
left join dept as d on e.deptno = d.deptno
```

After executing that query I am getting

```
id name sal deptno
------------------
1  a    100 10
2  b    200 20
3  c    200 20
```

but I want

```
id name sal deptno
------------------
1   a   100 10
2   b   200 20
3   c   300 20
```

Comment: Why would the row with id=3 name=c get sal=300 when the deptno=20? The issue seems to be that the dept table isn't properly normalized.

Comment: Use inner join instead

Comment: Are you sure you have correct join condition `e.deptno=d.deptno`? You have 2 rows with value 20 in one table and 2 rows with value 20 in other table, so SQL Server gets more results than you expect

Comment: When same department has 2 different salaries, what is the criteria for differentiation? Because, you are joining only on deptno, there is no way for system to decide if the salary has to be 200 or 300.

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
 update emp
 set sal = d.sal
 from emp as e
 left join dept as d on e.id = d.id
```

Comment: Can you list down the approach?Its better to understand the answer.

Comment: if the key has two values​​, it means that the key is not just one. 
can be more than one,or it's not the key.

Comment: Please update the answer with your explanation then?

Comment: if you look to table DEPT, the key is the column ID. 
DEPTNO column is not a key, because it has 2 values. 

if column ID in the table DEPT and  EMP is same, the query is true. 

but, if column ID in the table DEPT and  EMP is not same, the query wrong.